# how to make a blank cell after copy-paste

Tags: excel, if-statement, vstack, nonblank

After a conversion i get an excel file with multiple sheets.

i create a new sheet(1) and with `vstack` i stack the content from all sheets into the new sheet(1).
all blank cells from the original multiple sheets become "0"s
for a workaround, i use the formula

```
=if(vstack(..)=0,"",vstack(..))
```

i copy the columns from new sheet(1), where my data is into a new sheet(2) and paste only the values. (ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl, v)
the blank cells in new sheet(2) are false in isblank(cell) formula.

Any ideas why?

what i want to do next is to delete all blank cells

i tried this too:
`=FILTER(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet8!A1:O87),VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet8!A1:O87)<>"")` - #value error

Comment: a cell with the content of "" is not blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter a formula in excel there is not an option to have it return null or blank. This is a constant work around when you use excel. For your situation I recommend using an arbitrary set of characters then replacing those. Example:

```
=if(vstack(..)=0,"zzz",vstack(..))
```

Then when you paste, use the paste special of "Values". Next do a "Find and Replace" to find the "zzz" and replace with nothing.